# RelativeLayout is not becoming scrollable even after putting into ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have kept my RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView but still it is not becoming scrollable and also i am not getting extra space to drag and drop more view in my layout. plzz help..
I am new to android any answers will be a great help for me....Thanks in Advance.......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true" 
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b8fce8"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocProfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Doctor Profile"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDocName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDocProfile"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Name :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDocName"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tetSpecilazation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDocSpeciality"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDocQualification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tetSpecilazation"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Qualification :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocQualification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblDocQualification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDocQualification"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDocSpeciality"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDocName"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Specilization :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAddress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Address 1 :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtDocQualification"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblAddress1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="4"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDocQualification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblContact"
        android:text="Mobile No :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocMobNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCallMob"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtDocMobNo"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Call" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDocPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Landline "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDocPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCallPhone"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCallMob"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Call" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: first put relative layout inside that scrollview inside that linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--put here your button and all other-->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks..I will try that and let you know whether it works for me or not

Answer (score 0):

Actually it not works because of this

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

So the last component laid on bottom of Relative Layout and not stretching anywhere

If you want to stretch your Relative Layout try to add your component stack vertically each other with

```
  android:layout_below="@+id/yourComponentBefore"
```

i give it example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b8fce8"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ComponentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:background="#CFCFCF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ComponentTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ComponentOne"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ComponentThree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ComponentTwo"
        android:background="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks..I will try that and let you know whether it works for me or not